# jQuery Isotope plugin breaks layout when combination filters return no results and another correct set of filters is applied

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope, custom-post-type

Isotope handles the filtering and layouting of WordPress posts. The system works fine until no results are found using the filters, and applying correct set of filters **right after that**.

So the problem is:

1. As long as results are found (using filters) the plugin works well.
2. When no results are found, and I apply another correct set of filters right after that, the layout breaks.

I think Isotope loses the sense of width and / or height or something like that.

**Filters return no results:**

[image: Filters return no results]

**Filters return results again:**

[image: Filters return results again]

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

var $container = jQuery('#talot'),
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.talo-item',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });

$container.isotope('reLayout');

// filter buttons
jQuery('.filter a').click(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
    }

    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    // change selected class
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // store filter value in object
    var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
    // convert object into array
    var isoFilters = [];
    for ( var prop in filters ) {
    isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
    }
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    console.log(selector);
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

return false;
});

});
```

I added a console.log for selector for debugging and found the problem that way. Any help is greatly appreciated!

If you need more info, just ask and I will provide everything needed. Thank you in advance code wizards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (at least partial) solution I found myself is setting min-height CSS-property for the item class. I think it's a bit dirty solution so if anyone can come up with a "real one" feel free :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because plugin starts work untill all images loaded. For solving this problem you can use imagesLoaded, which is included in isotope. It is very easy to use this plugin - example of usage you can see [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin).